# Async Storage returning function instead of values

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, local-storage, asyncstorage

I'm trying to use AsyncStorage in my react native app and dont know why is not working.

Basically I want to have an indexed array (or a any key-value pair) stored in asyncstorage with true or false for every element that have been added.

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

....

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.storeData('favourites', []);
}

addOrRemove(id) {
    let favourites = this.getData('favourites');
    console.log('favourites getted: ', favourites);
    favourites[id] = favourites[id] ? false : true; //this logic is working fine
    this.storeData('favourites', favourites);
}
```

getData and storeData:

```
 storeData = (key, value)  => async () => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
        } catch (e) {
          // saving error
        }
    };

    getData = key => async () => {
        try {
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
          return value;
        } catch(e) {
          // error reading value
        }
    };
```

This is what I get when I do console.log('favourites getted: ', favourites);

```
favourites getted:  function _callee2() {
      var value;
      return _regenerator.default.async(function _callee2$(_context2) {
        while (1) {
          switch (_context2.prev = _context2.next) {
            case 0:
              _context2.prev = 0;
              _context2.next = 3;
              return _regenerator.default.awrap(_reactNative.AsyncStorage.getItem(key));

            case 3:
              value = _context2.sent;
              return _context2.abrupt("return", value);

            case 7:
              _context2.prev = 7;
              _context2.t0 = _context2["catch"](0);

            case 9:
            case "end":
              return _context2.stop();
          }
        }
      }, null, null, [[0, 7]]);
    }
```

When someone clicks on a specific button the method `addOrRemove(id)` is triggered. I want to get the array that I have stored in my AsyncStorage and put true or false in the id position of that array.

**Why I'm receiving that function from the AsyncStorage and not the indexed array that I want?**

*I think that can be an async/await problem, but don't know where is the issue.*

Comment: do you know that `getData` returns a Promise?

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm doing `const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)` in getData and then returning value. Maybe I'm wrong, but using await, `value` should be the array and not the promise, right?

Comment: you are defining getData as async function itself, the thing that you are waiting on is not getData. You are waiting on AsyncStorage.getItem which is another async call. I am not very familiar with reach but from a JS perspective you either also need to await getData or set the value from the body

Comment: Sure, you're awaiting inside an async function ... but the async function itself returns a Promise (which is what I said, nothing to do with what `getItem` returns, I said `getData` returns a Promise) ... therefore `let favourites = this.getData('favourites');` `favourites' is a Promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function "storeData" and "getData" return a async function, you can simplify :

```
 storeData = async (key, value) => {
   try {
     await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
   } catch (e) {
     // process error
   }
 };

 getData = async (key) => {
   try {
     const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
     return value;
   } catch (e) {
     // process error
   }
 };
```

And use them with async/await :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.storeData('favourites', []);
}

async addOrRemove(id) {
  try {
    let favourites = await this.getData('favourites');
    console.log('favourites getted: ', favourites);
    favourites[id] = favourites[id] ? false : true;
    await this.storeData('favourites', favourites);
  } catch (err) {
    //process error
  }
}
```